# Nginx Restrict Access to File

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Currently my config file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default) says

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location /credentials.js {
                deny all;
                return 404;
        }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

but I can still access credentials.js via example.com/credentials.js from the web. Any suggestions?

Comment: on what url you are able to access and what is the rest of the config?

Comment: I've updated my question with answers to your question.

Comment: Can you move the whole `/credential.js` block inside `location /`? and try again

Comment: That didn't fix it. Same results.

Comment: Run `nginx -T` and the output to your question

Comment: That command just outputted the configurations I have saved for my server, one of which is the one I posted above. Anything specific you want me to do with that?

Comment: So this is the only virtual server you have configured in nginx? How did you reload the config? Can you run `nginx -s reload`

Comment: Issue is fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding a `=` to your location, that will do an exact match:

```
server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80 default_server;

    location = /credentials.js {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location / {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200 "hello world\n\n";
    }
}
```

From the [nginx location docs:](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

> If an exact match is found, the search terminates. For example, if a “/” request happens frequently, defining “location = /” will speed up the processing of these requests, as search terminates right after the first comparison. Such a location cannot obviously contain nested locations.

Comment: @SamastVarma try the small example in the answer that should work, if required just change the server_name/port.

Comment: *'Still not working'*, did you forgot to reload the nginx configuration after changing? `location = /credentials.js` or `location ~* credentials.js` should deny the access of the file.

Comment: I updated my code last night with the `=` and reloaded but was still able to access the file from the web. I tried again this morning and it's correctly returning a 404. Thank you!

Comment: It works. You need to clear your browser cache. Otherwise, you still can download the file which you don't want others to access.